# How to create and update a UIProgressView in UITableVIew?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Sorry if this has been answered before but the other answers I came across did seem to have the answer I was looking for or use different 3rd party Frameworks like AFNetworking. I am using NSURLSessionDownloadTask and it's delegate methods to download in the background.

I want to have a UIProgressView in my UITableViewCell when the user wants to download something. I currently have it working but it's not pretty. The UIProgressView disappears when the cell is scrolled off the screen and if I accidentally click two different cells, a progress bar appears in both of them.

I think I am approaching the problem incorrectly and don't know where to fix it.

Here is my custom TableVeiwCell nib code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
}


- (IBAction)optionsButton:(id)sender {
NSNumber *indexRow = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.moreInfoButton.tag];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadEpisode" object:indexRow];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateProgressView:currentSize:) name:@"UpdateProgressBar" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setProgressViewMaxValue:) name:@"SetProgressMaxValue" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showProgressView) name:@"ShowProgressView" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideProgressView) name:@"HideProgressView" object:nil];
NSLog(@"Firing! %@", indexRow);
}

- (void)updateProgressView:(NSNotification *)notification currentSize:(int64_t)currentSize {
currentSize = [[notification object] longLongValue];
if (self.progressView.progress != self.totalBytes) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.progressView setProgress:((double)currentSize/(double)self.totalBytes) animated:YES];
    });

}

}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"progress"]) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.progressView setProgress:([object doubleValue]/(double)self.totalBytes) animated:YES];
    });
}
}


-(void)showProgressView {
[self.progressView setHidden:NO];
}

-(void)hideProgressView {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.progressView setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"Pushed hide progressview!");
});
}
```

Here is my DownloadManager code:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateProgressBar" object:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:totalBytesWritten]];
}
```

And here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath in for my TableView:

```
        if ([self.episodeModel.episodeDownloading isEqual:@"YES"]) {
        episodeCell.progressView.hidden = FALSE;

    } else {
        episodeCell.progressView.hidden = TRUE;

    }
```